# Using a trained classifier in an Android app

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, gaussian-process

As the title suggests, I'm attempting to train some different classifiers into an android app. The main question I have is how to represent the different models in a neat and effective way, from python to Java (Android Studio).

Background:
I will attempt to connect 3 bluetooth bio-marker sensors through an app in order to perform a medical classification on heart disease risk groups. I'm fairly experienced with the machine learning packages in Python, mainly Scikit learn. I want to try different classifiers (I'm thinking of Gaussian Process, neural net and support vector machine) to evaluate which to implement. When one is chosen I want to transfer the trained model into Android studio.

Is there a good way to represent models in scikit learn? What about non-parametric models such as GP?